# In a library, should I check if pointers are valid?

Tags: c

I've wondered this for a while and the necessity of checking whether pointers are valid or not in my own library is even necessary. Should I just expect the user to pass in the correct pointers because it's their job if they're using the library?

For example if I have a library which allocates and returns a structure

```
struct some_context{
    uintptr_t somedata;
};
struct some_context* createsomecontext(void){
    return malloc(sizeof(struct some_context));
}
```

But then I want to operate on that structture

```
void dosomethingwithsomecontext(struct some_context* ctx){
    //which is more valid here?
    assert(ctx);
    
    //or
    if(!ctx)
        return;
    
    //do something with ctx
}
```

Does it make more sense to call assert, or check if the structure is valid and return if it isn't?
Should I not even bother with checking the pointer and just assume the user is going to do the right thing?
And same thing with cleanup

```
void destroysomecontext(struct some_context* ctx){
    //Which is more valid?
    assert(ctx);
    
    //or
    if(!ctx)
        return;
    
    //do cleanup
}
```

What's more appropriate? assert, if ,or neither?
Similarly if I'm even writing a function to operate on a string?

```
void dosomestringoperation(char* str){
    assert(str);
    //or
    if(!str)
        return;
    
}
```

Should libraries ever do these checks ? At least in user mode, I can understand in the kernel since every device has access to the global memory and can cause a crash by not checking but does that imply even usermode applications should check for security/sanity reasons?

Comment: It is up to you if you want safety. But assert is a pretty good compromise since in release mode it does nothing (if NDEBUG is defined), so you won't have that extra check in this case.
But if you give it away, you should check especially if this part is invisible to the user. But simple return is a bit wild. You could just return a positive int on succes and negative on failure

Comment: Oh I actually didn't know assert was debug only! But what about for security reasons for example? I know softwares typically get exploited because they fail to check pointers or in case of string operations they don't account for length properly? Could this lead to a security flaw by using just assert instead of checking?

Comment: This is no different from any other precondition check. Whether you perform it or not is up to you, but performing a check and then silently returning on failure makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: You could make 2 libraries: `libKayla` and `libKayla_dbg` where the "debug" one has `assert`s and extra checks. The regular library "invokes UB when called with unexpected arguments"

Comment: Would it make more sense then to use an enum return type? To let the user know the pointer wasn't valid? But I guess my big concern is, is it bad practice if I don't check and does it lead to security vulnerabilities?

Comment: Or simply add an #if guard around that, and enable/disable the checks explicitly based on a macro constant. For example the standard libraries have some of these "debug magic macros"...

Comment: [*"“But what should I do, then, if somebody passes me a bad pointer?” 
You should crash. No, really."*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563).

Comment: asserts are immaterial. If you package the library with code compiled under `NDEBUG` it will not have the asserts even if the code using the library is compiled with debug information (and asserts available). Or is it supposed that users of your library will compile the library itself everytime?

Comment: @pmg I like the idea of using two separate libraries, by invoking UB do you mean just operating on the pointer as if you assumed it was valid? So the users could use the debug version to test their code and if checks pass then compile with the release version?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. `gcc -DNDEBUG ... -lKayla` or `gcc ... -lKayla_dbg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally one assumes that pointers are valid, especially given that, except for null pointers, you have no way to tell if a passed pointer is valid *for real* (what if you are given a pointer to unallocated memory, or to wrong data?).

An `assert` (possibly one that is active even in release builds, though) is a nice courtesy to your caller, but that's just it; you are probably going to crash anyway when trying to dereference it, so whatever.

By all means, though, do not silently return if you get a null pointer: you are hiding a logical error under the rug, making it harder to debug for your caller.

Comment: *By all means, though, do not silently return if you get a null pointer: you are hiding a logical error under the rug, making it harder to debug for your caller.*  Which is why a `void` return is the real problem in the code - there's no way to return an error condition.  And IMO `assert()` has two **fatal** flaws:  first, it can't be relied upon because it disappears if compiled with `NDEBUG` defined, and second, crashing the entire process instead of handling errors gracefully is extremely drastic.  I'd consider any library that meant to crash an entire process on bad input one giant turd.

Comment: If you are going to check the return value, you can instead check the pointer in first place.

Comment: Because code is always bug-free?  And bad input is the only reason something can fail?  So crash the entire process instead of returning a failure code just because someone didn't check one measly pointer?  Because returning an error code, logging the error, and having the functionality where the caller can retrieve the error message to know exactly what went wrong is too hard?

Comment: @and *"I'd consider any library that meant to crash an entire process on bad input one giant turd."* - So, like, [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)? Or, really, the entire C Standard Library? Not sure if everyone would call that *"one giant turd"*.

Comment: @IInspectable Quit being deliberately dense.  This is about using `assert()` to **deliberately** crash a program on bad input.  If you think that's a good idea, go ahead and tell your customers, "If you pass our code something we don't like, we're going to crash your entire process."  I bet you don't have the stones to do that, so you don't really believe what you just posted, now do you?  Either that or you know it's an unacceptably low standard that your customer won't accept.

Comment: @and My customers generally receive code that's compiled with `NDEBUG` defined, so any `assert()` I may have put there is gone anyway. That out of the way, I wasn't even suggesting to use `aasert()`'s at all. I was making the obvious point, that *"garbage in, garbage out"* is a common strategy, so common even that language support libraries embrace it. I don't see vendors of the C Standard Library feeling the need to justify that passing `NULL` into `strcpy()` can potentially terminate the calling process. If you are lucky, that is.

Comment: One thing I'm left (over)thinking is: what about documentation? Say a function fails if it receives a null pointer, in which case it immediately returns, doing nothing. You mention this in the function's documentation. But then you throw an assert in there, before the early return. Should the documentation still say it just returns if it gets a null pointer? That's the case in non-debug builds. But... in debug builds, it'll crash on the assert. Do you mention the assert in the documentation, qualifying what happens in debug and non-debug builds?

Comment: Fwiw, this page recommends calling out assertions in a function's docs: https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/assertions.html

Comment: Also fwiw, a `grep -ri "assert" *` of [glibc 2.37](https://mirror.fcix.net/gnu/libc/) reveals... a *lot* of `assert()` calls. So it seems like the GNU C Library employs a lot of asserts indeed. : p

Comment: @6equj5: if you document that the function fails "cleanly" on a null pointer, then it's part of the contract and it should not warrant an assert. An assert instead is ok if you just document that a null pointer for that parameter is not allowed.